# C++ documentation: create map of classes

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I've a C++ project structured like this:

- a main.cpp file in the root folder (where the doxygen_config file is contained)
- a src folder with all .cpp class files
- an include folder with all .h class files

Even if there's no hierarchy (no heritage and no interfaces) between the classes I've defined, is there a way to create an UML diagram with the classes printed as blocks, and some arrows to indicate if a class is member of another?
I've tried Doxygen but it creates only a class hierarchy indicating heritage.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Doxygen Manual: Graph and Diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) and [Doxygen Manual: Configuration](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_class_diagrams), you could install GraphViz, set `HAVE_DOT`, `EXTRACT_ALL`, `UML_LOOK` and `CLASS_GRAPH` as `YES` in configuration `Doxyfile`, and get what you want.